# Override label offset in Fieldset for Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I have a Fieldset in my layout, which contains a checkbox on the first line. For the main form I've set:

```
self.helper.layout_class = "create-label col-md-2"
```

which aligns my labels and fields and creates an "even" form.

The problem is, this gets applied within a fieldset and a checkbox gets shuffled to the right, description on the right, and it looks like it's just hanging in the middle of the screen:
[image: Checkbox in middle of screen]

This is because the generated html is applying the offset generated for labels, and ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="form-group row"> 
   <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
      <div id="div_id_allow_invitees_to_add_others" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" name="allow_invitees_to_add_others" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" id="id_allow_invitees_to_add_others"> 
         <label for="id_allow_invitees_to_add_others" class="custom-control-label">
         Allow invitees to add others
         </label>
```

If I manually remove the `offset-md-2` in the browser inspector, it displays exactly as I want - over on the left ...
I just moved the `Fieldset` to it's own `Div` in the hope I could override this, but no joy. That bit of the layout is fairly simple:

```
            Div(
                Fieldset(
                    _("Invitees"),
                    Field("allow_invitees_to_add_others"),
                    Formset("invitees"),
                ),
                css_class="",
            ),
```

Can anybody advise me on how to get this checkbox over on the left!